# How can I add a place to type user input in a jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to have user input in a program I am creating is there any way in a jframe in java to have a place a user can type things into.

Comment: JTextField ... JOptionPane

Comment: Please check out these links: 1) [Useful Swing Information and links](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) and 2) [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). Note that for future questions showing evidence of just a little more effort will go a long way towards getting better answers and more up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text Fields like JTextField, JFormattedTextField etc. For more details you can refer to [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) on Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Several java Swing GUI Components  allow for user input of which you can use in the JFrame.For instance, text fields provide formatted text input or password field behavior. I suppose you should get familiar with the swing GUI Components for you to make friendly user interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
package test20may2014;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Test20may2014 implements WindowListener{
static JTextArea foo;
static JTextField bar;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Test20May2014");
    jframe.addWindowListener(new Test20may2014());
    foo = new JTextArea(10,10);
    bar = new JTextField(10);
    jframe.getContentPane().add(foo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jframe.getContentPane().add(bar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jframe.pack();
    jframe.setVisible(true);
}
@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(foo.getText());
    System.out.println(bar.getText());
    System.exit(0);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```